# Azure custom domain not validating ownership

Tags: azure, dns, appdomain

We have three sites with three slots each and want to set up domain/ssl for all of them. TXT- and CNAME's are all set up.
It started off really good, and I was able to set domain/ssl for all but 2 which failed with "could not confirm ownership". Next day I tried again, and one of the two worked (we hadn't done any updates) but one still fails.

I get that this is a bug, but does anyone know of a workaround?

Comment: Any other message than "could not confirm ownership"?

Comment: None. I just says: "To verify domain ownership create CNAME and TXT record with your DNS provider using the configuration below, and replace {subdomain} with value of subdomain."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I had set up only one TXT record for the domain (not one per subdomain). The reason this was difficult to identify was that it worked for all subdomains except one.

Adding TXT records for all subdomains resolved the issue

Answer (score 1):

Kindly Check with your public DNS record provider whether this **`CNAME/TXT`** record for the last slot for which you are getting error "`could not confirm ownership`" has been correctly registered with public DNS zone hierarchy also please note that this error itslef state that these record couldn't be verified with your public DNS record provider.First Please check whether conditional forwarding from your internal DNS env has been correctly configured to the public IP/DomainRecord or not.